# Python, logging and design

Tags: python, logging

I have frequent doubts when I write python modules and classes, specifically:

Where/how should I put the main flag that controls logging and where/how to create the logger,

- Should it be at the module level? ---thus need to have some `global MyLogger` almost everywhere inside each method.
- Should it be an argument passed to methods and/or classes? Perhaps to decide if a method or class needed it or not, maybe I could use the `**args` stars magic, with call like `myMethod(..., logger=Mylogger)`?
- Where should I define/set the `I_logged_something` flag? (...or should I rely on the `if MyLogger: MyLogger.log('something')`)
- What about when the class or module is imported?

What is the Pythonic way of logging? How do you use the logging tools?

Answer (score 5):

You use logging everywhere, regardless.

In your modules, use:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and log away. Use the different levels (`log.info()`, `log.debug()`, `log.error()`, etc.) depending on what type of message you are logging.

Your main entry point then *configures* the `logging` module output. That can include completely disabling any output, or directing debug information to a file, but logging errors to the console.

Your modules do not need to care, the `logging` module handles configuration of the output handlers and formatting as global state.

Comment: More precisely, *you* handle logging configuration of handlers, levels etc. by calling appropriate logging code from your main entry point.